# Query string query with keyword and text fields in the same search

Tags: elasticsearch

Upgrading from Elasticsearch 5.x to 6.x. We make extensive use of query string queries and commonly construct queries which used fields of different types.

In 5.x, the following query worked correctly and without error:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "my_keyword_field:\"Exact Phrase Here\" my_text_field:(any words) my_other_text_field:\"Another phrase here\" date_field:[2018-01-01 TO 2018-05-01]",
      "default_operator": "AND",
      "analyzer": "custom_text"
    }
  }
}
```

In 6.x, this query will return the following error:

```
{
  "type": "illegal_state_exception",
  "reason": "field:[my_keyword_field] was indexed without position data; cannot run PhraseQuery"
}
```

If I wrap the phrase in parentheses instead of quotes, the search will return 0 results:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "my_keyword_field:(Exact Phrase Here)",
      "default_operator": "AND",
      "analyzer": "custom_text"
    }
  }
}
```

I guess this is because there is a conflict between the way the analyzer stems the incoming query and how the data is stored in the keyword field, but the phrase approach `(my_keyword_field:"Exact Phrase Here")` did work in 5.x.

Is this no longer supported in 6.x? And if not, what is the migration path and/or a good workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to rephrase the query by using different type of queries available for different use cases. For example use [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/query-dsl-term-query.html) for exact search on keyword field. Use [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/query-dsl-range-query.html) for ranges etc.

You can rephrase query as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "my_text_field:(any words) my_other_text_field:\"Another phrase here\"",
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "analyzer": "custom_text"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "my_keyword_field": "Exact Phrase Here"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date_field": {
              "gte": "2018-01-01",
              "lte": "2018-05-01"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We long have a long history of users creating elaborate advanced searches, which are then persisted as strings. In order to take the approach you are recommending we'd have to have a reliable way of parsing those search queries so that they can be reformatted in the Elasticsearch JSON structure--handling all of the search capabilities: field searches, parens, quotes, proximity search, NOT/AND/OR, date/timestamp ranges, etc. Do you know of a library which does this?

Comment: Use [HLRC](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.7/java-rest-high.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I see how the HLRC will help me here... If I have a query as in original post (or even more complex) and I am going to port it to Elasticsearch style JSON to make use of query_string, term, range, etc, I need to be able to parse the original string to identify search fields, nested parens, etc--similar to what Elasticsearch/Lucene does internally. Seems more complicated than simple regexes, so a library would be really helpful. Not sure if one exists, but I don't see any of that functionality in the HLRC.